# AlphaMasked images turning pink in Cycles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, image

I still cant seem to get this to work, I have the Image I need of a leaf and am trying to make it transparent. After all of this is set up using a mix shader and transparent shader the image is clearly found by Blender. In the Material view-port you can see the image on the plane, However in Rendered view it comes up with the missing pink colour. Please try and just chuck ideas out of how to help. Any ideas will be tested. Thanks Guys [image]

Comment: Are these smartphone photos? How about some actual **screenshots** where we can actually see what's going on in the shader panel?

Comment: Please make screenshots with Ctrl+F3 while in Blender window or press Printscreen button (if available) to make a screenshot, save it in image editing program and upload here. Also if you want to post 2 screenshots in 1 image do not rescale them, this makes them less possible to undertsand, thanks. Pink means that image isn't found so please pack all images in your file and [upload it here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texture appears pink in Blender Render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27105/texture-appears-pink-in-blender-render)

Comment: But this is in Cycles.? @Leander

Comment: Doesn't matter, probably the texture nodes image is not found anymore. I see you have marked icYous answer as accepted, so I guess you figured it out. @Sarsha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when an object turns pink it is because the original file got moved since you last opened Blender.

It is still showing up in your 3D window because that is using a different part of ram.

I would relocate the file and load it again and make sure "leaf" (leave lol) it where it is once you bring it in to Blender.

Comment: I  will test it and reply on what the outcome was. Many Thanks