# Why is my object pink in Texture Paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

The Structural_Material base color image selected in the UV window is the paint slot I'm trying to use. However, I can't paint anything because my model shows up pink. Anyone know why?

Please don't flag this as a duplicate of a question that is completely different, thanks. There are a number of reasons why a texture might be missing to cause something to show up pink in Blender lol.

Comment: are you sure you've assigned the good texture in the node editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Texture appears pink in Blender Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27105/texture-appears-pink-in-blender-render)

Comment: Possibly because 2.8 isn't ready for texture painting yet....

Comment: Tried it in 2.79 since someone mentioned 2.8 isn't ready for texture painting yet. The only difference is it's white instead or pink.
https://i.imgur.com/KriLLKu.jpg

Answer (score 2):

try to add a image texture node in the node editor then select in the node your chosen image.

let me know if it works.

Comment: Tried it in 2.79 since someone mentioned 2.8 isn't ready for texture painting yet. The only difference is it's white instead or pink.
https://i.imgur.com/KriLLKu.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Been messing with 2.8, and I found that I had to leave Texture Paint mode, and disconnect then reconnect the Texture node to get it to recognize the texture again. Dunno if that's the --**best**-- fix for this, but it does seem to work for now.

Comment: Confirmed to be working in 3.4

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the way that the Viewport draws now, and it is because it isn't updating properly. If you simply press from 'Solid' to 'LookDev' and back, you will usually see the texture appear on the surface of the mesh again like you expect. It is a common thing with 2.8, but 2.8 IS ready for texture painting already.