# A texture pink in Texture Paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

[image: screenshot of model in Texture paint mode showing pink area]

[image: screenshot of scene in object mode showing transparency]

For some reason some of the textures are pink in texture paint mode. Please help!

Comment: well, there are 2 options for material, one is for render and one is for viewport... go to your material settings, go down and there will be "viewport display", if you downloaded this object then it may be just that author used texture in solid preview

Comment: similar problem to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27105/texture-appears-pink-in-blender-render

Answer (score 1):

TL;DNR: You are in texture paint mode and don't have a texture image to paint on.  Return to object or edit mode using the drop down:

[image: 3D Viewport mode selector]

In your top image, you have the 3D Viewport in *Texture Paint* mode.  Texture paint mode is specifically for using Blender to create textures by painting on images.  The pink color is Blender's way of telling you that you don't have an image where you should have one.

This case is slightly different than when a material shows pink.  That's usually because the material's node group contains an *image texture* node and Blender can't find the file that contains the image.

In this case, the problem can be seen if you go to the *Texture Painting*, but unless you really want to set up a texture to paint, I think you should probably just go back to object mode.